# DynamoDB query with Lambda (node.js): Query key condition not supported

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I try to query my dynamoDB from a Lambda function. My table uses "id" as the hash key. I tried both versions below and received the corresponding error messages. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var params = {
        TableName : "addresses",
        KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id AND city = :city",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":id": "Austria",
            ":city": "Salzburg"
        }
    };
```

Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "Query key condition not supported",...}

```
var params = {
    TableName : "addresses",
    KeyConditionExpression: "city = :city",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":city": "Salzburg"
    }
};
```

Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "Query condition missed key schema element: id",...}

EDIT:

I now added secondary indices, but still get the same errors:

[image]

Comment: quering for  KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id"   works? and do you have range key?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried only using the id without the city condition and it works. How can I add additional conditions? I do not use a range key

Comment: i will answer it (to get +1 :) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if your hash key is 'id' then you cant query by:

```
KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id AND city = :city"
```

or by:

```
KeyConditionExpression: "city = :city"
```

you can query dynamodb only by hash and range key.

so your query should contain always hash key (id). if you want to query by 'city' also, you should add 'city' as range key to dynamodb table (or local secondary index)

then you can query for a record with `'id'` and `'city'`.

**update:**

if you want to query for `'city'`

```
KeyConditionExpression: "city = :city"
```

then you can just add global secondary index to the table.

Comment: are you added "IndexName": "city-index" to your query?

Comment: Thank you. it works now. Is there also a way to specify multiple indices in the indexName property. E.g. it i want to query for city, street and housenumber?

Comment: wow. that's a bummer. This makes dynamodb practically useless for my purpose. (e.g. querying street addresses)

Comment: yes.. using dynamodb is not always recomended. but you can try to think on build composite key. if your streets has codes, so your 'city' key can be 'NY-2'. then you can query for city+street

Comment: @EyalCh let's suppose we have city and state in our database. id is the hash key and city as the range key. How to query using city and state conditions?

Comment: @bazaglia its depend on your query. but if you want to query city and state so you need to add secondary index (city will be your hash, and state will be your range).