# AWS DynamoDB query with Key Condition Expression got an error: Query key condition not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services

The image below show my table's structure

[image: Table struture]

And try to querying the list of item with Java code below:

```
QuerySpec qs = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("RecordID >= :v_recordID")
                .withFilterExpression("DeviceID = :v_deviceID")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                            .withInt(":v_recordID", recordID)
                            .withString(":v_deviceID", deviceID)
                        );
```

I wanna to get items with RecordID greater than or equal 5, but it got an error:

> Query key condition not supported

How to solve it, thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DynamoDB query with Lambda (node.js): Query key condition not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318200/dynamodb-query-with-lambda-node-js-query-key-condition-not-supported)

Answer (score 1):

Check out link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

*The partition key equality test is required, and must be specified in the following format:*

*partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval*

Comment: But it's possible to have an "or" in that condition? like `partitionKeyName = :partitionKeyval OR partitionKeyName = :partitionKeyVal2`?